# Values from asp net form to Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Going from this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) what i am looking to do is to get the key value pairs sent by an aspnet/html form and then put them into a dto that i can then use elsewhere in my application. I see that inside the foreach loop

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
}

string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

try
{
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    // Show all the key-value pairs.
    foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
    {
        foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
        }
    }
```

you can read the values and send them to traceline. From there how would you go about turning them into a dto?

to go along with the example in the link. i want to get

```
public class trip{
    public string triptype {get; set;}
    public string airports{get; set;}
    DateTime? dates {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: create a "trip" object and populate the properties? Just like any other object?

Comment: ok, how exactly? That is what i am trying to get to.

Comment: `var tr = new trip();` Then within the loop, `tr.triptype = val;` or whatever. Adjust as appropriate depending on what the current key is. I guess maybe the keys correspond to to the property names of the Trip class? P.S. Are you actually trying to upload a file or anything as part of this? Because if not you can probably just use the Web API model binding functionality to directly map the uploaded data to the DTO, by making the DTO a parameter of the PostFormData method.

Comment: Im not uploading a file, how would i do that? I am replacing an asp form with an api end point which is why i am asking this.

Comment: The entire point of the article you linked to is to show how to upload files to Web API. If you're not doing that, then you don't need anything as complex as this code. Simple model binding will do it. Just make sure the "name" attributes on your form match the property names of the C# DTO object. Then you can do `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData(trip tr) {` and just start using the tr object immediately.

Comment: @ADyson going off creating a new object how do i match the key to the value when creating the new object in the foreach? tr.triptype = val but how do i tell it which key to get the value from?

Comment: I don't know what's in your keys or values so it's hard to say. You haven't given any sample data. But I'd try the suggestion in my last comment first, because it'll save you all that effort.

Comment: @ADyson im looking at this page here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#reading-form-control-data . Im trying to figure out how you say var triptype = key["triptype"].val

Comment: I know you are looking at that, and I'm saying _don't use that example_. Because that's all about file upload, which you've told me you're not doing. All this key-value stuff is entirely unnecessary. You can make a `trip` object a parameter of your action method and Web API will automatically populate it for you. This is the way Web API is meant to be used. See my comment above for a basic intro. I can write something up as an answer if you don't quite get it still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136381/discussion-between-leonardo-trimarchi-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've found a way round it now, but a simpler approach would be as follows, using the default model binding functionality built into Web API.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData(Trip tr)
{
   //do whatever you want here, you've already got a Trip object fully-formed (assuming the data is valid - the first thing you do you should be to check that):
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    //return an error to the client
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
  }

  //otherwise, carry on and do whatever processing you need
  ///...

  //last thing to do, return a response, something like:
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Your request has been processed");
}
```

For this to work, the only requirement is that the names of the properties of the "Trip" object match those being submitted from your form. Judging by the property names you've given in your answer, you'd just need to modify your Trip object very slightly:

```
public class Trip {
  public string trip { get; set; }
  public string options { get; set; }
  public string seat { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to do that, then do the opposite: modify the "name" attributes of the HTML form you're submitting from, so that they match the Trip object's property names.

And that's it - no need to manually populate the object properties from the form data.

Comment: this makes things much easier. I was operating under the assumption that since the form sends back Key + values and is not sending Json or sending data the way that Mvc forms send data now that this would not work. Thank you

Comment: nope. web api can accept serialised form data, or JSON, or even XML I think. Don't forget you could make actions which accept a GET request - the data can't be JSON then. You just set the content type when you make the request (for ajax, or system-system requests. For HTML form submission it gets set automatically by the browser). Anyway if the answer has helped you please consider upvoting / marking as accepted answer - thanks :-)

Comment: I tried to use it this way and received "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Trip' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'." and it would not hit the controller. If i change the controller from PostFile(Trip tr) it hits the controller but I am back to square one.

Comment: that's because that's the content-type to use when you want to send files. The default content-type for standard form data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Normally if you have a standard HTML form, there's no need to set a content-type at all, just delete that attribute and it will default to the standard one.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you! These are the types of things that are fun to learn and easy to miss. Thank you for being on SO!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in how to do this the way i found that worked for me was this. I dont know if this is the best way. I do know that since receiving values like this is not normally used commonly the answer was not clear.

```
var tr = new Trip
{
    Triptype = provider.FormData.GetValues("trip").FirstOrDefault(),
    Options = provider.FormData.GetValues("options").FirstOrDefault(),
    Seat = provider.FormData.GetValues("seat").FirstOrDefault(),
};
```